# int.TryParse not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is like this

```
string asd = "24000.0000";
int num2;
if (int.TryParse(asd, out num2))
{

    // It was assigned.
}
```

Now code execution never enters to if case, that means try parse is not working. Can any one tell me whats wrong with the code.

Note:In first step The value 24000.0000 is purposefully assigned as string .

Comment: Gotta ask, why is this question getting downvoted?

Comment: What is int.MaxValue on your System? What are your culture settings, in specific is . the decimal seperator or another seperator in your culture Settings?

Comment: @KaushalDeSilva - didn't downvote, but maybe because simply reading [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7.aspx) would have answered the question.

Comment: Simplest solution is to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27.aspx): `if (int.TryParse(asd, NumberStyles.Number, null, out num2))`

Comment: @Corak fair enough, but reading the documentation answers almost every question on SO. Also, I did not know about the overload Chris is talking about, so I've learnt something :)

Comment: @KaushalDeSilva: I didn't downvote,  but maybe it's because you ask, "why doesn't int.TryParse work when I pass it something that's not an int?"

Comment: @JohnSaunders I didn't ask the question, was just wondering because I thought it was a valid question. I don't think its that crazy to (mistakenly) assume 24000.000 is an int

Comment: Well, the documentation should be the first place to look. SO strongly encourages its users to first try to find a solution by themselves and only to ask if they don't. Especially for very clear cases like this. Also, the question reads a bit like "I am the only one who found an error in a method that thousands of developers have been using daily for years and haven't been able to find". (unfair exaggeration, i know)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the second `TryParse` overload that allows you to specify `NumberStyle` parameters to allow for decimals.

```
int val =0;
var parsed = int.TryParse("24000.0000", 
                NumberStyles.Number, 
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, 
                out val);
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use the `NumberStyles.Number` value instead as it will also cover white space, thousands separators, and possibly most important of all: negative signs. As it is now, inputting `-24000.0000` will fail.

Answer (score 8):

For an `int`, you cannot have decimal places.

EDIT:

```
string asd = "24000.000";

int dotPos = asd.LastIndexOf('.');

if (dotPos > -1) {
   asd = asd.Substring(0, dotPos);
} 

int num2;

if (int.TryParse(asd, out num2))
{
 // It was assigned.
}
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by other answers, there are better ways to deal with the conversion.

Comment: Can you please tell me what work around I can do to remove decimal places and make it an integer so that I can do some mathematical calculations on it.

Comment: @AthulKSurendran: Simplest solution is to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27.aspx): `if (int.TryParse(asd, NumberStyles.Number, null, out num2))`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Cool. I can never recall all the overloads for these conversions. Cheers for pointing that out dude :)

Answer (score 3):

See the remarks section of the MSDN documentation on this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

The string can only contain whitespace, a sign, and digits.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
string asd = "24000.0000";
int num2;
decimal tmpNum;
if (decimal.TryParse(asd, out tmpNum))
{
    num2 = (int)tmpNum;
    // It was assigned.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've asked it to parse an `int` but given it a `double` or `float`. Since it can't parse the number it'll return false and set `num2` to zero.